# DLL references from subtrees/submodules in VNEXT Build

Tags: git, tfs, msbuild

Basically, when migrating to microsofts VNEXT-build (AND GIT), our DLL references from subprojects have stopped working.

Previously we had a mainproject1 and a subproject1 as seperate TFS-repos, subproject having dependencies to mainproject. We specified that the TFS-build-template should include Mainproject1 and subproject1 , whereupon TFS seemed to handle DLL-references automatically

After migrating to git and including mainproject1 as a subtree in subproject1 and switching to VNEXT, however, it seems the build agent uses a different folder structure, giving us: The type or namespace name 'X' could not be found.

Watching the logs, I can see that the mainproject gets built successfully, allthough the subproject can't find it automatically.

Does anyone know how the new system actually works? Has anyone tried anything similar, or knows how to instruct the build server to search for the dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding two conditional HintPaths in the .csproj file. The first one checks for the local dll (as it is placed by the build agent), the second one looks for the same dll but in the GAC.